# C++ передача списка чисел

Tags: c++

Нужно передавать функции или конструктору список чисел определенного типа, например, int, uint8_t или uint32_t. Как это сделать просто, производительно и так, чтобы работать с этим список как с массивом, то есть уметь обращаться по индексу?

Есть такой код:

```
#ifndef FIELD_H
#define FIELD_H

#include <cstdint>
#include <initializer_list>


namespace field
{

    class FieldElement
    {
        uint8_t chunks[5];

    public:
        FieldElement(std::initializer_list<uint8_t> a);

    };

    FieldElement zero();
    FieldElement one();
}

#endif
```

Нужно иметь возможность создать элемент конечного поля из списка чисел или массива байт. Как это сделать? Использовать std::tuple? Какие еще средства для этого есть?

Comment: std:array? http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: std::vector<T>&?

Comment: А тут требуется передача массива определенной длины или произвольной длины?

Comment: Массив из пяти uint8_t или uint32_t. Думаю, подойдет std::array

Answer (score 1):

Напишите тело конструктора:

```
FieldElement::FieldElement(std::initializer_list<uint8_t> a) 
{
     std::copy_n(a.begin(), 5, chunks); 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Просто и производительно**, попробуйте так:

```
FieldElement(const std::initializer_list<uint8_t>& a);
```

или так:

```
FieldElement(std::initializer_list<uint8_t>&& a);
```

```
namespace field {
class FieldElement {
    std::array<uint8_t, 5> chunks;

public:
    FieldElement(std::initializer_list<uint8_t>&& a) {
        const size_t size = chunks.size();
        auto it = a.begin();
        for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            if(i < size) { //initializer_list size larger than chunks.size()
                    chunks[i] = *it;
                    ++it;
                }
            }
        }

    };

    FieldElement zero();
    FieldElement one();
}



int main() {

    field::FieldElement({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}); //initializer_list size larger than chunks.size()
}
```